# Is it possible to decrease length of unity laucher?

Tags: 16.04, launcher

Is it possible to decrease the unity launcher length like docky? NOT size.

Comment: You might consider Ubuntu Mate

Answer (score 0):

not unless you go into the code and hack it yourself, you will also need to deal with other code that assumes its full width.

It would probably be easier to switch to something like gnome3 instead of unity of you want that behaviour.

This explains how to enable gnome3
http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/how-to-install-gnome-320-in-ubuntu.html